# Need Help Using a 2-Dimensional Array

Tags: android, imageview, android-arrayadapter, android-drawable

So I made this custom 2d array adapter(basically copied it from someone else, so I don't completely know what I am doing with it), because I am making a checkers board game, and I wanted the board to be a 2d array of imageviews. I'm just wondering: How do I actually access each individual item in this 2d array in my main activity. I know in the OnClick it gives me both the view that is selected and the position, but I was just wondering if there is any way that I can do something like array[row][column].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.piecered2) in my main activity.

```
public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;
ImageView[][] gridContent;
int rowPosition, columnPosition, count;

public GridViewAdapter(Context c, ImageView[][] content){
    context = c;
    count = 0;
    gridContent = new ImageView[content.length][content[0].length];
    for(int i = 0; i<gridContent.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<gridContent[i].length; j++){
            gridContent[i][j] = content[i][j];
            count++;
        }
    }
    rowPosition = 0;
    columnPosition = 0;
}

public int getCount() {
    return count;
}
public int getRowCount(){
    return gridContent.length;
}
public int getColumnCount(){
    return gridContent[0].length;
}
public Object getItem(int rowNum, int columnNum) {
    return gridContent[rowNum][columnNum];
}
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup group) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if(view == null){
        imageView = new ImageView(context);
    }
    else{
        imageView = (ImageView) view;
    }
    columnPosition = position % gridContent[0].length;
    rowPosition = (position - columnPosition)/gridContent[0].length;

    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 100));
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

    //Just Setting Up the Initial State of the Board Here
    if(columnPosition%2 != 0 && rowPosition == 6){
        setRed(imageView);
    } else if(columnPosition%2 == 0 && (rowPosition ==5 || rowPosition==7)){
        setRed(imageView);
    }

    else if(columnPosition%2 != 0 && (rowPosition == 0||rowPosition==2)){
        setBlack(imageView);
    } else if(columnPosition%2 == 0 && rowPosition == 1){
        setBlack(imageView);
    }

    return imageView;

}

public Object getItem(int position){
    return null;
}
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Didn't you just post the solution yourself:

```
ImageView[][] gridContent;

// fill the array

// ...    

gridContent[row][column].setImageResource(yourresource);
```

will set the image-resource for the ImageView, assuming "gridContent" is a 2D array of ImageViews.
Just make sure that the array is actually filled with ImageViews that are already initialized with "= new ImageView(this)". Otherwise you will run into a NullPointerException.

Furthermore, I would suggest that you change your getItem() method to the following:

```
/** use ImageView as the return type instead of Object */
public ImageView getItem(int rowNum, int columnNum) {
    return gridContent[rowNum][columnNum];
}
```

This will enable you to do the following in your Activity:

```
GridViewAdapter adapter = new GridViewAdapter(this); // make sure the adapter contains a filled ImageView array
adapter.getItem(row, column).setImageResource(yourresource);
```

Comment: I did that, but it didn't work. It didn't error, but it just didn't work. It was running the line of code, but it just wasn't doing anything. I made a for loop that initializes all the items in the 2d array of imageviews (that I am putting in the gridview) like you said: myArray[a][b] = new ImageView(this)